# How can I disable iGoogle?

Tags: igoogle

So I tried out this new iGoogle feature and liked it for some days, but now I'm sick of all the mess and just want good old google.com back. Is there a way to disable iGoogle again with all the clutter?

Comment: Since iGoogle is being shut down, this question doesn't have much value any more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can click Classic Home on your iGoogle homepage.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. I'm getting iGoogle even though I'm visiting google.com and there is no such link to the Classic Home, nor can I find anything in the settings screens. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, click the gear on the iGoogle page at top right corner. A drop down list will appear, and select "Classic Home."